# "no such property: p1 for class: Script3" while setting XML transform on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, xslt, groovy

I am trying to fetch some `xsl:message` in an XSLT transform on a groovy script running on a Jenkins machine and I get `no such property: p1 for class: Script3`.

Here is the code:

```java
    final FileOutputStream compareOutputFile = new FileOutputStream(/*outputHtmlFile*/)
    final Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(new StreamSource(new FileReader(/*transforXslFile*/)

    final String firstSourceFile = /* */
    final String secondSourceFile = /* */
    transformer.setParameter("firstSourceFile", firstSourceFile)
    transformer.setParameter("secondSourceFile", secondSourceFile)
    final StreamSource streamSource = new StreamSource(new FileReader(/*emptyXmlFile*/))
    final StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(compareOutputFile)

    String result
    try {
        final ErrorListener errorListener = new ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            void warning(final TransformerException e) throws TransformerException {
                result = "Warning " + e.getMessage()
            }

            @Override
            void error(final TransformerException e) throws TransformerException {
                result = "Error " + e.getMessage()
            }

            @Override
            void fatalError(final TransformerException e) throws TransformerException {
                result = "Fatal " + e.getMessage()
            }
        }
        transformer.setErrorListener(errorListener);
    } catch (final Throwable e) {
        return "Error while setting listener: " + e.getMessage()
    }

    try {
            transformer.transform(streamSource, streamResult)
            result = "All good"
    }
    catch (final Throwable e){
            return "exception " + e.getMessage()
    }
    return result
```

This method is annotated with `@NonCPS`.

Then, I `echo` the return value of this method in the caller method. And I get `Error while setting listener: No such property: p1 for class: Script3`.

If I'm not mistaken, it could be because the `result` variable is not accessible within the `ErrorListener` definition scope.

How can I fetch these `xsl:message` (which all have the attribute `terminate="no"`) to have them to mark the pipeline step as failed on Jenkins ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a scope issue.

Using a public field on created ErrorListener to access it resolved the issue.